# Why does C program crash when dereferencing pointer to an array?

Tags: c, windows, pointers, mingw, double-pointer

I have a simple C code:

```
int main()
{
    int test[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int **ptr = &test;

    printf("%d\n", (*ptr)[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

As soon as it reaches the `printf` line, it crashes:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 0.865 s
```

When compiling the code on Ubuntu, it gives me the warning:

```
test.c:8:17: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     int **ptr = &test;
```

However, if I instead dynamically allocate the memory on the heap, the code works:

```
int main()
{
    int *test = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        test[i]=i;
    }
    int **ptr = &test;

    printf("%d\n", (*ptr)[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Please explain to me, why the code works when the array is on the heap, but not on the stack?

Comment: `main.c:5:11: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing
      'int **' with an expression of type 'int (*)[10]'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    int **ptr = &test;`

Comment: `[cquery] incompatible pointer types initializing 'int **' with an expression of type 'int (*)[10]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`, no need to compile...

Comment: `int *ptr = test;` and `printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);` seems like a saner/the intended use case.

Comment: FYI, `int **ptr = &test;` is not valid C. With `-pedantic-errors` GCC gives a error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get your `ptr` variable to be the "address of an array of integers" you actually need a rather more subtle (and arcane) declaration.

This will work:

```c
int (*ptr)[10] = &test;
```

as it declares that, when dereferenced (i.e. when you then actually *use* the expression `*ptr`), it will be an array (of 10 elements).

In some ways, the structure of the declaration is a bit like that for [pointers-to-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/10871073).

EDIT: In your second case, `test` is a plain old pointer (with a value assigned to it by the `malloc` call); as such, it is itself a *variable* whose address can be taken (as your `int **ptr = &test;` line does - correctly).

However, in the first case ('fixed' array), `test` refers to a block of memory; in many ways, this can be *used* as a pointer to the first element (like it will be in a function call, for example). But what value can the compiler possibly assign to the "address of the address of the first element?" This is what fails in the attempted assignment using `&test` in this case.

But, you would be entitled to ask, according to the previous paragraph, how does the compiler determine a value for `&test` (to assign to `ptr`) with the code given in this answer? Well, if you add the following line to your program:

```c
printf("%p %p\n", test, &test);
```

you will see that `test` and `&test` (you can change `&test` for `ptr` - the output will be the same) have **exactly the same value**! Thus, using this 'arcane' declaration, you give the compiler enough information to know what to do with the "array pointer" - basically, it sort of 'ignores' (or bypasses) the first level of dereferencing, ending up with the address of the array's first element (as is).

Comment: But what is the difference between a pointer to the first element and an array? Shouldn't the [] access produce the same result?

Comment: @Victor2748 See edit - hope it makes thigs a bit clearer.

Comment: I see, I guess I'll look into differences between array and pointer storage. Thank you.